# iOS UITableViewCell with UIContextMenuConfiguration: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6328155-context-menus-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started#toc-anchor-006) of [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com) to display a context menu when long pressing on a `UITableViewCell` and came up with the following simplified version to test the implementation:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
        
    override func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView,
        contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint)
        -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

            let identifier = "\(indexPath.row)" as NSString
            
            return UIContextMenuConfiguration(
                identifier: identifier,
                previewProvider: nil) { _ in
                    
                    let shareAction = UIAction(
                        title: "Share",
                        image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")) { _ in
                            print("share")
                    }

                    return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, children: [shareAction])
            }
    }
}
```

The `ViewController` is a plain `UITableViewController` with Static Cells in the Storyboard. When I run the application and long press the table cell then the code works as expected, but I get the following AutoLayout errors in the console and I do not understand why?

```
2020-07-06 15:22:36.879780+0200 Test[1033:453998] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x282308780 h=--& v=--& UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x102833490.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231bca0 UILabel:0x102921c50'Share Item'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x283939420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231bcf0 UILabel:0x102921c50'Share Item'.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x283939420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282315db0 _UIInterfaceActionGroupHeaderScrollView:0x103063600.width == _UIPreviewPlatterActionsTitleView:0x102921590'Share Item'.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231a800 H:|-(0)-[_UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0'']   (active, names: '|':UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x102833490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231a850 _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0''.trailing == UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x102833490.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28232fd40 _UIInterfaceActionGroupHeaderScrollView:0x103063600.width == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0''.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231cfa0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(12)-[UILayoutGuide:0x283939420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIPreviewPlatterActionsTitleView:0x102921590'Share Item' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231bc50 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x283939420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(12)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIPreviewPlatterActionsTitleView:0x102921590'Share Item' )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231bcf0 UILabel:0x102921c50'Share Item'.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x283939420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-07-06 15:22:36.881528+0200 Test[1033:453998] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2823088c0 h=--& v=--& UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x102833490.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231b070 groupView.actionsSequence....height >= 44   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x103062e00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823135c0 V:[_UIInterfaceActionGroupHeaderScrollView:0x103063600]-(0)-[_UIInterfaceActionVibrantSeparatorView:0x10283ab40]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823140a0 V:[_UIInterfaceActionVibrantSeparatorView:0x10283ab40]-(0)-[groupView.actionsSequence...]   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x103062e00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231ada0 UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x102833490.top == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0''.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231adf0 V:[_UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0'']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x102833490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282314190 _UIInterfaceActionGroupHeaderScrollView:0x103063600.top == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0''.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823141e0 groupView.actionsSequence....bottom == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x1028336f0''.bottom   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x103062e00 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28231b070 groupView.actionsSequence....height >= 44   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x103062e00 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You have a duplicate constraint somewhere. It looks like your `Share Item` has a `.leading` a `.trailing` and a `.width` constraint. The `.width` constraint conflicts with `leading` and `trailing` because those set the `width`.

Comment: I never set up any constraints in the Storyboard or in the code. I don't know where to change them?

Comment: I am also getting a constraint conflict when showing a context menu from a collection view cell. It appears to be coming from the menu view itself, which is laid out by the OS automatically, just as your code snippet shows. I'm guessing this is a bug in iOS 13? Anyone have any confirmation that the problem is outside of our ability to control?